# Rendering an array of data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render some filtered xml data into a web page. The data is in an array and is pictured below.

[image: Xml Data format]

This is my code at the minute but I am very lost.
I have tried many different variation but they all seem to result in:

1. either not rendering anything to the webpage
2. a error stating that resValue "cannot be used as a child" or something along those lines.

Currently this code doesn't bring up any faults - it just doesn't render the array.

I am new to React and web development in general.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```jsx
export default function Home() {
  // State to store value from the input field
  const [resValue, setResVal] = useState("");

  // Input Field handler
  function handleRes(event) {
    setResVal((resValue) => event);
    console.log(resValue);
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {resValue.map((item) => {
            return <li>{item}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // State to store value from the input field
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  // Input Field handler
  const handleUserInput = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  // Reset Input Field handler
  const resetInputField = () => {
    setInputValue("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="InsideContent">
        <Input
          className="input1"
          placeholder="Paste PoB Code"
          name="pobCode"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={handleUserInput}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="InsideContent">
        <Button1 onClick={() => handleRes(loadPoBXml(inputValue))}>
          Confirm
        </Button1>
        <Button2 onClick={resetInputField}>Reset</Button2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

EDIT:
Phil has said that to properly fix this I need to make my loadPoBData method synchronous. So here it is I also added my decodePoBString method too.

```
function loadPoBXml(str) {
var res = decodePoBString(str)
var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(res);   
let gem = (xml.getElementsByTagName('Gem'));
let item = (xml.getElementsByTagName('Item'))
return gem}

function decodePoBString(str) {
return inflateSync(new Buffer(str, "base64")).toString()
```

Comment: That doesn't look like XML. Looks more like a plan JS array of objects

Comment: Its possible it gets converted from xml to a js array. 
The starting data for that array is from a xml document.

Comment: What does `loadPoBXml` do? What does it return?

Comment: I think the point Phil was making is that by alluding to XML in your question we expect it to be __about_ XML. XML is a "red herring". This is about how to render JSON.

Comment: Ahh i see apologies, like I said i'm very new to react and js.

Comment: The loadPoBXml inflates and decodes a string -> turns it into a xml  doc and then it returns that xml doc. I figured that the object it returned was a xml object but it must be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you're trying to render something in the return value for an event handler. This won't work because any return value is ignored / discarded.

Rendering should be done in the return value of your component. Assuming `loadPoBXml()` is synchronous, all you need to do is have it set your `resValue` state and map over it in your JSX.

```jsx
export default function Home() {
  // If resValue is meant to be an array, initialise it as one
  const [resValue, setResVal] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  // Confirm button click handler
  const handleClick = () => {
    setResVal(loadPoBXml(inputValue));
  };

  // Input Field handler
  const handleUserInput = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  // Reset Input Field handler
  const resetInputField = () => {
    setInputValue("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="InsideContent">
        <Input
          className="input1"
          placeholder="Paste PoB Code"
          name="pobCode"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={handleUserInput}
        />
      </div>

      {/* assuming you want to render resValue here */}
      {resValue.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {resValue.map((item, i) => (
              <li key={`item${i}`}>{item.name}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}

      <div className="InsideContent">
        <Button1 onClick={handleClick}>Confirm</Button1>
        <Button2 onClick={resetInputField}>Reset</Button2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, Is making something synchronous as simple as adding a async tag to the function?

Comment: @Bigred absolutely not. If `loadPoBXml` is asynchronous, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72824645/edit) to include the details and I'll attempt to address it in my answer

Comment: Thanks Phil. I'm not sure I've done it all correctly but it certainly worked.